# How could I get the controls in onListItemClick from ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

I have ListActivity in Android Project. Its code:

```
public class ListActivityApp extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list); 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();        
    map.put("title", "my note");  
    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.paper));
    listItem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();        
    map.put("title", "second");  
    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.paper));
    listItem.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();        
    map.put("title", "cos tam");  
    map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.paper));
    listItem.add(map);

    SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.list,
            new String[] {"img", "title"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.title});
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);       
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String selection = getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, selection, 0).show();
}}
```

My list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView  
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
/>
<TextView
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="Empty"   
/>
```

And my item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The first problem (resolved) I have: on the emulator I can see three TextViews with text "Empty", but when I've clicked each of them I can see Toast with correct "title". What I am doing wrong? In another project it works properly. - I have resolved this one. In this:

```
SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem,       R.layout.list, new String[] {"img", "title"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.title});
```

I should as a third argument use the R.layout.item, not R.layout.list.

The second problem: how can I get the Object of the my list item in the onListItemClick(..) method? I have of course position and id.
l.getItemAtPosition(position)
getListAdapter().getItem(position)
These methods return all item (in my case img and title). How can I for example change the text in TextView or set my ImageView invisible in onListItemClick(..)?

Comment: I can get the text from TextView in this way: `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
  map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListAdapter().getItem(position);  String temp = (String) map.get("title");` But I can't do for example: `TextView tv = (TextView) map.get("title");` to change the text. How can I modify the existing controls in ListView from ListActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the textview and imageview from the clicked item, use the View, v, given to you in the onClick() event and do the following:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText("example text");
ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
```